# Dynamic imports using complicated path in React/JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am working on an app where I don't know the names/paths of the components that I might need during rendering. And I don't want to/can't write all the import statements at once during rendering either. 
I tried the React lazy loading function with import() to load my components as and when I need them, but turns out import() doesn't support *complicated* urls, like `'../../data/files/components/MyComponent'`.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by complicated url? Looks pretty simple to me?

Comment: What do you mean you do not know the names/paths of the components that you might need to use? The example url you provided would work if MyComponent is located in this directory: `../../data/files/components/`

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic imports are not really dynamic in wepback(and other bundlers).
It is needed to be statically analyzable, because webpack pre-loads all dependencies for all chunks before runtime phase.
So basically these statements will NOT work:

```
const magic = '../unknown/path/to/' + a + b;
import(magic).then(...
```

Because magic, a and b variables can be known only in runtime and it's fully unknown at build phase.
But if you will give webpack as much information as you can, webpack will do it's best to load your files:

```
const fileName = ...some heavy calculations for filename;
import('../../data/files/components/' + fileName + '.js')
```

Webpack will do following steps:

1. Scan for all files in the '../../data/files/components/' folder
2. Find only files with endings '.js'
3. Will remember it for the moment when you will need your file in runtime and will pass correct variable and give you the component you need